# About the method of onBindview() in Swithpreference.java in andorid source code

Tags: java, android

```
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);

    View checkableView = view.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.switch_widget);
    if (checkableView != null && checkableView instanceof Checkable) {
        if (checkableView instanceof Switch) {
            final Switch switchView = (Switch) checkableView;
            switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        }

        ((Checkable) checkableView).setChecked(mChecked);

        if (checkableView instanceof Switch) {
            final Switch switchView = (Switch) checkableView;
            switchView.setTextOn(mSwitchOn);
            switchView.setTextOff(mSwitchOff);
            switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mListener);
        }
    }

    syncSummaryView(view);
}
```

I  have  a question about why here first judge the switch_widget and setOnCheckedChangeListener(null); Is the R.id.switch_widget used for many SwitchPreference,So we need to clear it,right? but the previous SwithchPreference don't need to set monitor ?

Comment: Please try rephrasing your question. I, personally, am not clear on what you're actually asking.

Comment: My qustion  is that why must  switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)  firstly?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> My qustion is that why must switchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null) firstly?Thanks!

You would have to look at the history of the file to see if there's comments clarifying why the code is set up that way. However, *generally speaking*, you will clear a listener if **you do not want to invoke it with the code that follows**.

Since this code just wants to set the initial state of the view, it does not want to invoke a listener that should be normally invoked when the state *changes* (like in response to a user click). So, to prevent that, the listener is saved, cleared, and then restored after the checked state is updated.

Hope that helps!